# Issue whie generating auth signature in salesforce

Tags: rest-api, callout, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-api

I am facing an issue while generation Auth signature in salesforce. I tried to test the API from Postman and it works well with key and token. Even when I change the Authorization Header in Apex to the postman request header it works well but if I use the code to generate auth signature then Response is always Unauthorized access.

```
    String nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
    String timestamp = string.valueof(dateTime.now().getTime()/1000);
    String companyId = '123145730762509';
    String APIURL = 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/'+companyId+'/account/1';
    Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>();
    parameters.put('oauth_consumer_key', Consumer_Key);
    parameters.put('oauth_nonce', nonce);
    parameters.put('oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1');
    parameters.put('oauth_timestamp', timestamp);
    parameters.put('oauth_version', '1.0');

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res;
    req.setEndpoint(APIURL);
    req.setMethod('GET'); 
    String signature = generateSignature(req, Consumer_Secret, '', parameters);



private static String generateSignature(HttpRequest req, String consumerSecret, String tokenSecret, Map<String,String> parameters) {
    String s    = createBaseString(parameters, req);         \
    Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), 
               Blob.valueOf(consumerSecret+'&'+
                            (tokenSecret!=null ? tokenSecret : '')));
    String signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
    System.debug('Signature: '+signature);
    return signature;
}


private static String createBaseString(HttpRequest req, Map<String,String> parameters) {
    Map<String,String> p = parameters.clone();
    String host = req.getEndpoint();
    Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
    if(n>-1) {
        p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
        host = host.substring(0,n);
    }
    List<String> keys = new List<String>();
    keys.addAll(p.keySet());
    keys.sort();
    String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
    for(Integer i=1;i<keys.size();i++) {
        s = s + '&' + keys.get(i)+'='+p.get(keys.get(i));
    }

    return req.getMethod().toUpperCase()+ '&' +
        EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' +
        EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Base String :-

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F123145730762509%2Faccount%2F1&oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdFawAAiD3SLud6d5RvREaVOoAn%26oauth_nonce%3DMPqopi%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1480179972%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Comment: you might want to peruse my question here  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25341/using-oauth-1-0-encoded-requests-for-external-webservice-calls
I had similar problems 2 years ago and it was stumping me for weeks until I finally solved it.

Comment: Thanks @akarnid. I tried with the solution and done some changes but getting the same error.

Comment: Are you writing out the base string to system debug?  Does the signature generated by generateSignature method match the signature in Postman exactly?

Comment: Signature generated by generateSignature method does not match even I fixed the value of timestamp and nonce value to postman generated values.

Comment: @HiteshGupta I am having the same issue. I know this is 5 years old post but do you remember what was your fix for this?